# Android Studio - JSON Data

Tags: java, android, json

I've made a "Google maps Activity" on Android Studio, but to add markers i'm using JSON. (my first ever time using JSON)

Basically when the google maps opens, it loads a 'marker' on the location (String strJson) which contains the data. The marker displays the name and country, but I can't seem to get the 'latlng' to work. I've tried...

```
Int latlng = Integer.parseInt(jsonObject.optString("latlng").toString());
```

But the   'gMap.addMarker'  doesn't allow 'Int'

Does anyone know how i could do this?

CODE:

```
String strJson= "{\"Location\" :[{\"name\":\"Gladiator Fitness\",\"latlng\":[\"53.2286362\",\"-0.5856869\"],\"country\":\"GB\"}]}";

try {
    JSONObject jsonRootObject = new JSONObject(strJson);
    //Get the instance of JSONArray that contains JSONObjects
    JSONArray jsonArray = jsonRootObject.optJSONArray("Location");

    //Iterate the jsonArray and print the info of JSONObjects
    for(int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++){
        JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
        //Search the database for the "data"
        String name = jsonObject.optString("name").toString();
        String country = jsonObject.optString("country").toString();
        //Add marker for each location
        gMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(53.2286362,-0.5856896)).title(name).snippet(country));
    }
```

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rINlo.png) is a screenshot of the same code.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes, please include the code directly in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    String strJson= "{\"Location\" :[{\"name\":\"Gladiator Fitness\",\"latlng\":[\"53.2286362\",\"-0.5856869\"],\"country\":\"GB\"}]}\n";

    try {
        JSONObject jsonRootObject = new JSONObject(strJson);
        JSONArray jsonArray = jsonRootObject.optJSONArray("Location");

        //Iterate the jsonArray and print the info of JSONObjects
        for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
            //Search the database for the "data"
            String name = jsonObject.optString("name").toString();
            String country = jsonObject.optString("country").toString();
            JSONArray latlng = jsonObject.optJSONArray("latlng");
            double lat = latlng.optDouble(0);
            double lng = latlng.optDouble(1);

            Log.d("JSON", "coords: " + lat + " " + lng);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.d("JSON", "e: " + e);
    }
```

Comment: Oh nice yes it does work! thanks! but how do i use that to draw the location of the 'marker'? I've tried...   gMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(jsonObject.getJSONArray("lat").getDouble(0),
                        jsonObject.getJSONArray("lng").getDouble(1))).title(name).snippet(country));

Comment: `gMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(lat, lng)).title(name).snippet(country));`

Comment: WHAT!? i tried that earlier and it didn't like it ! Thanks mbmc for the help really appreciated :)!